# Import pandas on docker with tensorflow

Tags: python, pandas, docker, machine-learning, tensorflow

I am using Windows and learning to use tensorflow, so I need to run it under Docker (Toolbox).

Following the usual instruction:

```
$ docker run -it gcr.io/tensorflow/tensorflow
```

I can launch a Jupyter notebook on my browser at `192.168.99.100:8888` and run the tutorial notebooks without problems.

Now when I try to `import pandas as pd` , which is installed in my computer with pip, on Juypter it just said `ImportError: No module named pandas`

Any idea how I can get this library to work inside the tensorflow images launched from docker?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ms340.jpg)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Docker `image` should be built on a `linux` operating system. You should launch a `shell` inside the Docker `image` `grc.io/tensorflow/tensorflow` to install the requisite python dependencies.

See Docker [quickstart](https://docs.docker.com/engine/quickstart/) for using

```
docker run -it grc.io/tensorflow/tensorflow /bin/bash
```

and then

```
sudo apt-get install python-pandas
```

according to [pandas docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/install.html#installing-using-your-linux-distribution-s-package-manager).

To avoid doing this every time you launch the image, you need to `commit` the change to create a new `image`.

To `commit` the change, you need to get the `container` `id` (after `run` and installation steps above):

```
sudo docker ps –a # Get list of all containers previously started with run command
```

Then, `commit` your changes `git` style using the `container_id` displayed in the container list you just got and giving it an `image_name` of your choosing:

```
sudo docker commit container_id image_name
```

The new `image` will now show up in the list displayed by `sudo docker ps –a`.

If you get a free `docker` account you can `push` and `pull` your updated `image` to your `docker` `repo`, or just keep it locally.

See [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/containers/dockerimages/) under 'Updating and Committing your image'.

Comment: Following the instruction, it says ``E: Unable to locate package python-pandas``

Comment: See also here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/672338/unable-to-locate-package-python-pandas

Comment: This works for the current run.
However, when I run the next time, I have to repeat the whole process to download and install pandas again. Any clue how to avoid this?

Answer (score 5):

For **windows** users:

```
docker run -d -p 8888:8888 -v /c/Users/YOUR_WIN_FOLDER:/home/ds/notebooks gcr.io/tensorflow/tensorflow
```

Then use the following command to see the name of your container for easy execution commands later on (the last column will be the name):

```
docker ps
```

Then run:

```
docker exec <NAME OF CONTAINER> apt-get update
```

And finally to install pandas:

```
docker exec <NAME OF CONTAINER> apt-get install -y python-pandas
```

(the -y is an automatic 'yes' to stop a prompt from appearing for you to agree to the installation taking up additional disk space)

Comment: Thanks. It worked. /home/ds/notebooks. what is this? which path should i give here. without this also it worked.

Comment: Glad to hear it helped :) The second folder is just the destination folder into which you would like to map your windows source folder. I deliberately left it with some default value as I believe most users wouldn't necessarily care where the docker's tensorflow image resides as long is had some required files mapped into it (if you wanted to use some data files that reside on on your windows machine you would have to use such a mapping).

Comment: Many thanks:) "docker exec <NAME OF CONTAINER> apt-get upgrade -y python-pandas "  can i use this to upgrade pandas?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an image with the pandas installed - 
https://hub.docker.com/r/zavolokas/tensorflow-udacity/
Or pull it `docker pull zavolokas/tensorflow-udacity:pandas`